# Why can I pass the key of std::map to a function that expects non-const?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, constants, stdmap

According to `std::map` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), it stores the key-value pairs in `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, so the keys in the map are const.

Now imagine that I have an `std::map` where the keys are the pointers to some objects.

```
struct S {};
struct Data {};
using MyMap = std::map<S*, Data>;
```

Let's also assume there is a function `foo` that accepts `S*` parameter.

```
void foo(S* ptr) { /* modify the object (*ptr) */ }
```

Now, the question is: when I iterate over `MyMap` with range-based for-loop, I am able to pass the map element key to `foo`:

```
MyMap m = getMyMapSomehow();
for (auto elem : m)
{
    static_assert(std::is_const<decltype(elem.first)>::value, "Supposed to be `const S*`");
    foo(elem.first); // why does it compile?
}
```

So, even though my `static_assert` succeeds (so I assume that the type of `elem.first` is `const S*`), the call to `foo` compiles fine, and therefore it look as if I'm able to modify the object behind pointer-to-const.

Why am I able to do that?

**P.S.** Here's a [live example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62254cd9bd872a7d) that illustrates my point. For brevity, I use `int` instead of `S` and `Data`.

Comment: You're making a copy of the element; you can do whatever you want with that personal copy...

Comment: Don't confuse a pointer to const with an immutable pointer!

Comment: @KerrekSB ah, indeed! My brain confuses me at the end of my working day :) Thanks!

Comment: Happens to the best :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so I assume that the type of `elem.first` is `const S*`

No. The key stored in `map` is `const`, that means for `std::map<S*, Data>`, the key will be `S* const` (i.e. `const` pointer), not `const S*` (i.e. pointer to `const`). So it's fine to pass it to `foo(S* ptr)`, the `const` pointer itself will be copied to the parameter.

Comment: You are right, I mixed `const T*` with `T* const`. Such things sometimes happen at the end of the work day :-) Thanks!

Comment: @VasiliyGalkin: One note: though `const X*` and `X const*` are the same thing, making a habit of writing `X const*` is helpful especially when working with template and typedefs if you think  *visually* .

Comment: @Nawaz nah, I wouldn&#39;t agree to that. But I wouldn&#39;t want to start yet another `const T*` vs `T const*` holywar either ;)

Comment: @VasiliyGalkin: Think *visually*:  `using pint = int*;` then what does `const pint` mean? `const int*`? or ... ? :-/

Comment: @Nawaz I strongly believe that typedefs for raw pointers to some type is in general very bad practice. So let's just agree that we disagree on this matter ;)

Comment: @VasiliyGalkin: If that is your "belief", then that cannot be argued against! If `T` is a template parameter whose value is `int*`: then what does `const T` mean? Is it `const int*`? or ... ? ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150226/discussion-between-vasiliy-galkin-and-nawaz).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler example, see if you can work it out:

```
void f(int);          // takes a non-const int

int main() {
    std::set<int> s;  // elements are const ints
    for (auto n : s) {
        f(n);         // OK!?
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, indeed! I didn't pay enough attention to the fact that the key type is `T* const` rather than `const T*`. Thanks!

Comment: `auto n` makes a copy and then `f(int)` takes a copy. So I didn't understand what this answer is trying to explain by using copies!

Comment: @Nawaz: this is basically the same situation as the OP faces: A function taking a non-const value can be called with a (copy of a) const set element. Note that the code wouldn't work if you had `f(int&)` and `for (auto& n : s)`. I understand there's a second level of confusion, but I think if you can wrap your head around the simple example, you have enough differential information to ask the right question about the original situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: *"Note that the code wouldn't work if you had `f(int&)` and `for (auto& n : s)`"*. Both of them need not to make copy. Having either `f(int)` or `auto n`  would work!

Answer (score 1):

`std::map<K, V>::value_type` is `std::pair<const K, V>`, as you mentioned.  So what is `const K` when `S*` is substituted for `K`?  The answer, which might surprise you, is not `const S*`. but rather `S* const`.